# Deletelater not responding in qt

Tags: c++, qt, events

I am asking this question second time and I did not find a solution that I am not so familiar with qt events.This is my code:

```
class My_worker :public QObject{};
```

I have a function in that class that will send data periodically with a timer in it.

```
My_worker::process{

   Qtimer my_timer=new Qtimer();

   my_timer->setInterval(time_ms);

   connect(my_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this(sendData()))

}
```

So with function `sendData()` I am sending data with the my_timer elapsed. this is my thread doing the work. I create these in my `QCoreapplication` class. so:

```
 class My_Application: public QCoreApplication{};
```

In constructor I define the signals and threaa like this.

```
 My_Application::My_Application{

 //First I create an object of My_worker

 My_worker my_worker=new My_worker();

 //Then I create a thread and move my worker to thread

 QThread my_thread=new QThread();

 my_worker->moveToThread(my_thread); 

 // then I connect the signals.

 connect(my_thread,SIGNAL(started)),my_worker,SLOT(process())); //So starts processing

 connect(my_worker,SIGNAL(finished()),my_thread,SLOT(quit()));

 connect(my_thread,SIGNAL(finished()),my_thread,SLOT(deleteLater))));

 connect(my_worker,SIGNAL(finished()),my_worker,SLOT(deleteLater()));


}
```

And finally my dataSend() function is;

```
void dataSend(){

//do some work

// **if I emit my finished signal here I see that the destructor of my_worker is called**
```

}

But I dont want to emit the signal here and I want to destruct my_work when my My_Application is finished.

So in My_Application destructor I try to delete my_worker so the destructor is

```
  My_Application::~My_Application(){

  cout<<"the destructor called for app"<<endl;

  if(my_worker->thread())

     connect(my_worker,SIGNAL(destroyed()),my_thread,SLOT(quit()));

     my_worker->deleteLater(); // this does not work and does not call my_worker destc.


 }
```

Comment: It won't get called because, if your `QApplication` object is being destroyed, then the event loop has stopped running. Without the event loop running, no `deleteLater` events will get processed.

Comment: my_worker->deleteLater() won't be called as expected because there is no event loop in the thread my_worker was moved to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might solve your problem:

```
class My_worker :public QObject, public QRunnable{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    My_Worker() : loop(0) {}

    void run();

public slots:
    void sendData();
    void quit();

private:
    QEventLoop *loop;
};
```

My_Worker.cpp

```
void My_Worker::run(){
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(time_ms);
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendData()));

    loop = new QEventLoop;
    loop->exec();

    delete loop;
}

void My_Worker::quit(){
    if (loop){
        loop->quit();
    }
}
```

My_Application.cpp

```
My_Application::My_Application(){

    My_worker *my_worker=new My_worker();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), my_worker, SLOT(quit()));
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(my_worker);

}
```

See the documentation for further information about the [QThreadPool](https://qt-project.org/doc/QThreadPool.html), [QEventLoop](https://qt-project.org/doc/QEventLoop.html) and [QRunnable](https://qt-project.org/doc/QRunnable.html) classes.